# Where can I download Access 2003 sample database Northwind.mdb

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

I am looking to find the 2003 version of the MS Access Northwind database because I want to look at the switchboard functionality which is not used in the later Northwind database versions.

Since Microsoft no longer supports 2003, it is no longer available for download on their website.

Are there any other SAFE websites that make this available for download? If so, could some kind soul please point me to it?

Thanks.

Not sure why this is getting voted down. I am trying to grasp how to use the switchboard to hyperlink to websites, pdf files located on our server, and functions. I understand the older version of this database might cover this. I see it as very related to coding since the sample database will guide me in that direction. I really want to see how a switchboard works before asking specific coding questions related to this.

Please enlighten me as to the errors of my ways on this post. If I can't post this question here, then where can I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a sample download here:

http://www.accessforums.net/code-repository/microsofts-northwind-database-example-7735.html

It did not help me much though. It wasn't using the switchboard manager functionality. Oh well. Now I know.